# Offset html scroll-behavior

Tags: html, css

I have the following layout:

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior:smooth;
}

header {
  height: 234px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  padding: 24px;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dedede;
}

nav {
  height: 88px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 234px;
  padding: 24px;
  background: #f5f5f5;
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <p>I'm the header</p>
</header>

<section>
  <p>I'm a video</p>
</section>

<nav>
  <a href="#1">Section 1</a>
  <a href="#2">Section 2</a>
  <a href="#3">Section 3</a>
</nav>

<section id="1">
  <p>I'm section 1</p>
</section>

<section id="2">
  <p>I'm section 2</p>
</section>

<section id="3">
  <p>I'm section 3</p>
</section>
```

As you can see, I have the main header at the top of the page with `position: sticky;`. I then have a `<nav>` further down the page which sticks underneath the main header. You can then click the links to scroll to each `<section>`.

When clicking on each link in the `<nav>`, each `<section>` scrolls to the very top the page.

Is there a way to offset the top position? In this case, I'd need to offset from the top by 322px (`<header>` and `<nav>` heights combined).

I've tried adding a `:before` pseudo element to each `<section>` with a height of 322px, but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding:

```
section {
  padding-top: 370px;
}
```

`<header>` + `<nav>` are actually 370px. 234px + 88px + 2x24px of padding. 2, not 4 because padding is collapsed between them.

Comment: I don't want to add visible spacing to the start of each `<section>`.

Comment: If it's css only solution i think this is the right approach. Just add: `section::first-of-type {padding: 0;}` and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

It is a little bit hacky, but works for your case.
Add a class `.section` for each section and a span inside with the ID.

```
<nav>
  <a href="#section1">Section 1</a>
  <a href="#section2">Section 2</a>
  <a href="#section3">Section 3</a>
</nav>

<section class="section">
  <span id="section1"></span>
  <p>I'm section 1</p>
</section>

<section class="section">
  <span id="section2"></span>
  <p>I'm section 2</p>
</section>

<section class="section">
  <span id="section3"></span>
  <p>I'm section 3</p>
</section>
```

Then, absolutely position each span 322px up.
It is also necessary to add z-index to the header and nav due to the relative position of the sections.

```
.section {
  position: relative;
}
.section span {
  top: -322px;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
}
header, nav {
  z-index: 1;
}
```